# table is not showing in a php loop

Tags: php, oracle, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problem when showing a table in a bootstrap environment with PHP and ORACLE DB. My code is like this,

```
<body>
    <?php
    $projectName    = strval($_GET['project']); 
    $headmarkValue  = strval($_GET['headmarkValue']);

    $sql = "select * from fabrication where PROJECT_NAME = :project and HEAD_MARK = :headmark order by HEAD_MARK ASC";
    $fabUpdateParse = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

    oci_bind_by_name($fabUpdateParse, "headmark", $$headmarkValue);
    oci_bind_by_name($fabUpdateParse, "project", $$projectName);

    oci_execute($fabUpdateParse);

    while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($fabUpdateParse)){
        echo $row['HEAD_MARK'];
        var_dump($row['HEAD_MARK']);
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

the problem is I cant show anything inside the while loop? Which is if I want to show a table from DB, I have to use while loop. Please help me, what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: what do you get if you var_dump($row) instead?

Comment: You have two variables with 2x `$$` try removing one.

Comment: omg such a stupid mistake.... thank you so much I guess I am too stressfull

Answer (score 1):

You're using 2x `$` signs for `$$headmarkValue` and `$$projectName`.

This is known as [**Variable variables**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

You need to use just one dollar sign in order to be used as a regular [**variable**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).

```
oci_bind_by_name($fabUpdateParse, "headmark", $headmarkValue);
oci_bind_by_name($fabUpdateParse, "project", $projectName);
```